# /var/log/kern.log full of "kernel: [259030.323390] failed hdr12 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00"

Tags: kernel, logs

I checked my logs today, with journalctl, and lo and behold, my journal is full to the brim with the repeated line below:

```
kernel: [259030.323390] failed hdr12 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

They are in `/var/log/kern.log`, and there here are dozens instances of that line every second.

The internet has no info I can find about what those are or how to make them stop.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Kubuntu, actually, 20.10.